# Batch Renaming of Files in Linux Shell

Tags: linux, rename, filenames

I am working via ssh on a remote cluster and need to rename some files according to a scheme.
The rename should work like:

`M-19-3778_P1-DX5-K47-232-Elev_A1-A1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz` into
`M-19-3778-P1-DX5-K47-232-Elev-A1-A1L001_R1.R.fq.gz`

`M-19-3778_P1-DX5-K47-232-Elev_A1-A1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz` into
`M-19-3778-P1-DX5-K47-232-Elev-A1-A1L001_R1.F.fq.gz`

`M-19-3779_P1-F48-F37-86-Cont_A2-A2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz` into
`M-19-3779-P1-F48-F37-86-Cont-A2-A2L001_R2.R.fq.gz`

`M-19-3779_P1-F48-F37-86-Cont_A2-A2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz` into
`M-19-3779-P1-F48-F37-86-Cont-A2-A2L001_R2.F.fq.gz`

...

`M-19-3830_P1-DX5-D12-221-Elev_F9-F9_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz` into
`M-19-3830-P1-DX5-D12-221-Elev-F9-F9L001_R53.R.fq.gz`

`M-19-3830_P1-DX5-D12-221-Elev_F9-F9_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz` into
`M-19-3830-P1-DX5-D12-221-Elev-F9-F9L001_R53.F.fq.gz`

Iterations are only in the beginning of the names with 3778....

So far I've tried it with combinations of `grep`/`sed`/`cat` but did not succeed.
And I have no idea how to handle the iteration in the end of the name `R1`, `R2`,..., my guess would be a combination of a `for` loop and an `if`-Statement but I just don't get this running.

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain how the destination file name is derived from the source file name(s). Show the "combinations of `grep`/`sed`/`cat`" you tried and explain what's wrong with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i=1
for name in *
do
    newName=${name%_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz}L001_R$i.R.fq.gz
    mv "$name" "$oldname"
    ((i++))
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I had to change "$oldname" in the mv command in line 5 to "$newName" but then it worked.